# How can i animate a sprite while pressing right key on xna 4.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna-4.0

I have an sprite sheet on my xna project that i am trying to make, here is the thing:
I want to animate the sprite but i don't know exactly how to do it, i want that when i press the right key button, paint a new sprite from the sprite sheet, so i can animate the sprite.

here is a part from the code i want to animate:

```
    if (Player.ismoving == false)
    {
        Player.child_currentframe = new Point(0, 0);
    }
    if (Variables.direction == "right")
    {
        Player.child_currentframe = new Point(0, 1);
    }
    if (Player.timer == 0)
    {
        Player.child_currentframe = new Point(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: This is covered in the [Intermediate Platformer Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) from MSDN. Get the source code, you'll learn plenty of things.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handled sprite animations in my own game was to make a Spritesheet class that more or less did the following:

```
public sealed class Spritesheet
{
    public Rectangle[] TextureCoordinates { get; private set; }
    public Texture2D Texture { get; private set; }
}
```

Then, in the `SpriteBatch.Draw()` call, you pass in the Spritesheet's Texture and a specific TextureCoordinate Rectangle to define where on the sheet you're pulling the image from. From there, it's just a matter of having your Sprite choose the right image to draw from the spritesheet.

This would look something like

```
if(Variables.direction == "right")
{
    Variables.imageIndex += 1;
}
```

With the `imageIndex` being used as the index of the Spritesheet's texture coordinates.

Comment: It's mostly templating and comment fluff, but here's the full file I use for my own game. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bUr00Aj2